# ScriptProcessorNode Skipping

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have the following javascript code:

```
var audio = null;

try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    audio = new AudioContext();
} catch (e) {
    alert("Web Audio API is not supported in this browser");
}

var scriptNode = audio.createScriptProcessor(1024, 0, 1);

var pos = 0.0;

scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
    var output = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;

    for (var channel = 0; channel < output.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
        var data = output.getChannelData(channel);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = Math.sin(pos);

            pos += 2.0 * 3.14159 * 440.0 / audio.sampleRate;

            while (pos >= 2.0 * 3.14159) {
                pos -= 2.0 * 3.14159;
            }
        }
    }
}

scriptNode.connect(audio.destination);
```

I am trying to access the audio loop of web-audio, much in the way that a low-level audio streaming API would work in C.  This code is supposed to play a 440 Hz tone continuously until the page is closed.  The code will play the tone, but after a second or two the sound skips repeatedly, suggesting I've run out of buffer space and the script isn't being called each buffer period.

I'm sure the solution to this is simple, but what's actually causing the skipping?  How can I get this script to run continuously?

EDIT: The skipping goes away if I refresh the page.  Is this a browser bug?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the buffer size of the ScriptProcessor node from 1024 to something larger.  Or use 0 to let the browser choose a value for you.

Note also ScriptProcessors are deprecated, but the replacement isn't yet available.  The replacement should behave better.

Comment: Wait... they deprecated something without making a replacement first?  Seriously?

Comment: I still get skipping if I give it 0, though :/

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated. Doesn't mean you can't use it right now, but expect it to go away eventually.

Comment: Instead of 0, try 32768, the max size.  What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: 16384 works, but that's a huge amount of latency.   I get skipping with 4096, which is also too much latency.

Comment: I'm using chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: The correct value depends on many things including how fast your machine is and how good the OS is in handling the threading, and on how Chrome handles the buffering.  File a bug against chrome at crbug.com/new.

Comment: They marked the report as "Won't Fix" because of the deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

For example, interval is 4 sec,

```
var audio = null;

try {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext ||     window.webkitAudioContext;
    audio = new AudioContext();
} catch (e) {
    alert("Web Audio API is not supported in this browser");
}

var INTERVAL = 4;  // 4 [sec]

var scriptNode = audio.createScriptProcessor(1024, 0, 1);

var pos = 0.0;

var elapsedBuffer = 0;

scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
    var output = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;

    for (var channel = 0; channel < output.numberOfChannels; channel++) {
        var data = output.getChannelData(channel);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            elapsedBuffer++;

            if (elapsedBuffer > audio.sampleRate) {
                if (elapsedBuffer > (INTERVAL * audio.sampleRate)) {
                    elapsedBuffer = 0;
                }

                data[i] = 0;

                continue;
            }

            data[i] = Math.sin(pos);

            pos += 2.0 * 3.14159 * 440.0 / audio.sampleRate;

            while (pos >= 2.0 * 3.14159) {
                pos -= 2.0 * 3.14159;
            }
        }
    }
};

scriptNode.connect(audio.destination);
```

[XSound.js](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/XSound) is very useful library for Web Audio API.